# The "Tools" file is missing in the sdk file, what do I do?

Tags: android

So, I wanted to install android studios to test my unity application on my phone, but when I tried opening the Android/sdk file the tools file was missing.

I tried reinstalling android studios but that didn't work either, does anyone have any suggestions for what I can do?

Comment: Configure SDK path manually

Comment: I have no idea how to do that :|

Comment: Are you following the official documentation?